# Ignoring tests in Infinitest

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, silktest, infinitest

I am automating system tests using Silk4J. Silk4J is based on JUnit. In addition I am testing my helper classes using pure JUnit tests.

Now I need to tell Infinitest which tests shall be considered for running immediately. I will choose the unit tests only, not the system tests, of course.

The Infinitest preferences have no options. How to tell Infinitest which tests to run (or which tests not to run)?

I have read [Is it possible to specify which tests to choose from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518552/is-it-possible-to-specify-which-tests-to-choose-from), which seems to be a perfect match, but it didn't work for me. The given link returns HTTP 404. I don't have enough reputation to comment nor to start a bounty for updating the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because the class name needs to include the package name or `.*` at the beginning to match any package name.

See [Infinitest User Guide](http://infinitest.github.io/doc/user_guide.html) for details.